# How to determine injectivity and surjectivity for the following linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, real-numbers

1) $T: P_2(\mathbb R)\rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ defined by $T(p(x))=(p(0), p'(0))$

2) $T: M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $T(A)=a_{11}+\cdots+a_{nn}$

In terms of the first one, since $\dim(V) > \dim(W)$, it is not injective. Then I don't know how to express it in matrix form, so how would you determine the surjectivity?

For the second one, I totally have no idea.

Could someone help?

Comment: Since these are vector spaces, it is enough to check the kernel. Basically you can say that a linear transformation $T : V\rightarrow W$ is one-to-one if $KerT=\{0\}$. If $\dim(V)-\dim(KerT)=\dim(W)$ then you can say that $T$ is onto.

Comment: In the expression "dim($V$)$\gt$dim($W$) I noticed an odd lack of space before and after the "$>$" and I clicked on "edit" and saw that only three characters in this expression were in MathJax.  I changed it to $\dim(V) > \dim(W)$, with the whole thing between just one pair of dollar signs, coded as \dim(V)>\dim(W) and consequently with proper spacing.  The backslash in \dim not only prevents italicization but also provides proper spacing before and after $\dim$, as in $A\dim B$ and $A\dim(B)$ (where you'll notice less space after $\dim$ in the second expression than in the first). $\qquad$

Comment: You say $\dim(V)>\dim(W)$ without saying which spaces you're calling $V$ and $W$.  I'm assuming you mean $\dim(P_2(\mathbb R))>\dim(\mathbb R^2)$. $\qquad$

Comment: I'm a bit confused about $p'(x)$ showing up in the first one. That's going to be a linear function, not number, unless $P_2(R)$ means something I'm not expecting.

Comment: Your definition of the first transformation makes it appear to be from $P_2(\mathbb R)$ to $\mathbb R\times P_1(\mathbb R)$, rather than to $\mathbb R^2$. And $\dim(\mathbb R\times P_1(\mathbb R)) = 3$, so your inequality on dimensions is not correct. $\qquad$